# How to scrape the html page that provides more information while scrolling down by using python lxml

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml.html

I am scraping the text from https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/p/parsoch01.html.
But I cannot scrape the contents that is located below the "Total" table in the page. I want to get the number from "Total" and "Advanced" table but the code returns nothing.
It seems that the page loads additional information as the user scroll down the page.

I ran the code below and succeeded to get the data from player's profile section and "Per Game" table. But cannot get value from "Total" table.

```py
from lxml import html
import urllib
playerURL=urllib.urlopen("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/p/parsoch01.html")
# Use xpath to parse points per game.
ppg=playerPage.xpath('//tr[@id="per_game.2019"]//td[@data-stat="pts_per_g"]//text()')[0]# succeed to get the value
total=playerPage.xpath('//tr[@id="totals.2019"]//td[@data-stat="fga"]//text()')// I expect 182 to be returned but nothing is returned.
```

Is there any way to get data from the lower part of this page?

Comment: you need to use a selenium driver for async data load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the content you wanna extract from that site is within comments. BeautifulSoup can't parse content from comments. To get the result you need to uncomment first so that BeautifulSoup can access it. The following script does exactly what I tried to say:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/p/parsoch01.html"

r = requests.get(URL).text
#kick out the comment signs from html elements so that BeautifulSoup can access them
comment = r.replace("-->", "").replace("<!--", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
total = soup.select_one("[id='totals.2019'] > [data-stat='fga']").text
print(total)
```

Output:

```
182
```

Comment: Appreciate! I just used Inspect elements function in Chrome to check the actual code of the page and did not check the actually retrieved code by lxml. The page seems that it automatically comments out the lines for tables that aren't displayed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open your web browsers' console and test the xpath to see if it's finding the element you're looking for.

```
$x("//tr[@id='totals.2019']//td[@data-stat='fga']//text()")
```

Returns an Array object.

```
$x("//tr[@id='totals.2019']//td[@data-stat='fga']//text()")[0]
```

Accesses the value you want.

Also:

```
# comments in python start with '#' not '//'
```

Comment: Thank you I confused the python's comment symbol with othrer language. I typed your code to the console in Chrome and got 182, which is the number I want. But when I tried to scrape the value from Python, it doesn't work.